# How to use numpy.sort for ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In my program, I try to get the top 10 array items with their indices. The type of array is `ndarray`.

```
for a in arr:
   print(a)

(0, 112354) 0.11235445
(0, 875) 0.155235445
(0, 6135) -0.14445445
...
```

I try to use `numpy.sort` for this and pass the array as a parameter, but it does not give the needed result.

How do I get the top 10 array items and their indices?

**UPDATED**

The `pprint(arr)` output is

```
<1x28382 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 18404 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`print(arr)` returns:

```
 (0, 11098) 0.113315317878
  (0, 6775) 0.0513432082411
  (0, 5107) 0.0544519626112
  (0, 98)   0.059766413309
  (0, 27042)    0.104718642966
  (0, 22622)    0.104718642966
  (0, 6135) 0.104718642966
```

Actually `arr` is `sklearn.svm.SVC.coef_` object.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you provide (a) your code, (b) an example of inputs and what you *want* to get, (c) an example of inputs and what you *actually* get?

Comment: Please include a pprint of your array and on which axis you want to sort

Comment: print discard useful informations. can you give the output of arr[:2] to understand the structure ? on what do you want to sort ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a sparse matrix, it's more efficient to work on `a.data`.

A simple example :

```
from numpy import *
import scipy
a=zeros(12,int)
a[:6]=range(6)
shuffle(a)
a=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(a.reshape(4,3))
print(a.toarray());print(a)

# a is
[[4 0 1]
 [3 0 5]
 [2 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]

# or in csr format
(0, 1)  5.0
(0, 2)  3.0
(1, 2)  2.0
(3, 0)  1.0
(3, 1)  4.0
```

Then find the n biggest values, and the row and col associated indices:

```
n=3 # the three biggest 
bigs=a.data.argsort()[:-n-1:-1] 
r,c=a.nonzero()
R,C=r[bigs],c[bigs]
print("the 3 biggest are in ",*zip(R,C))
```

that gives :

```
the 3 biggest are in  (0, 1) (3, 1) (0, 2)
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. Updated the question.